# Build HAProxy Config from HTTPD Puppet Manifests

Tags: puppet, haproxy

We currently manage a cluster of Apache HTTPD servers with Puppet. The each web server uses `profile::web_server::redundant` which looks like this:

```
class profile::web_server::redundant inherits profile::web_server {
  ::apache::mod { 'userdir': }

  include ::ourweb::sites::site1_example_com
  include ::ourweb::sites::site2_example_com
  include ::ourweb::sites::site3_example_com

  # Other general webserver configuration
}
```

Each website looks something like this:

```
class ourweb::sites::site1_example_com {

  $site_root = '/var/www/sites/site1.example.com'
  $port     = '8001'
  $port_ssl = '8401'

  # Checkout site from VCS

  # Add $port to firewall

  apache::vhost { 'site1.example.com':
    servername      => 'site1.example.com',
    port            => $port,
    docroot         => $site_root,
  }
  apache::vhost { 'site1.example.com_ssl':
    servername      => 'site1.example.com',
    ssl             => true,
    port            => $port_ssl,
    docroot         => $site_root,
  }
}
```

We are planning to move from a proprietary load balancer to HAProxy and we want to avoid creating an additional manifest for every site. Is there a (simple) way to have the HTTPD servers use the information they need from the manifest and have the HAProxy servers use the same manifests with just the information they need?

Additionally, instead of giving HAProxy a list of backend servers, can Puppet make that list based on which systems have this manifest applied? For example, if `ourweb::sites::site1_example_com` is applied to `server1` and `server2`, but `ourweb::sites::site2_example_com` is applied to `server2` and `server3`, the HAProxy configuration will contain the correct values for each frontend.

Comment: 1.Take a look at parameterized classes: https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/lang_classes.html#defining-classes. 2. It is unclear specifically what you are asking, but you are either describing an ENC, Hiera, or exported resources. Bonus: do not inherit classes in Puppet; that is bad practice and leads to undesired results.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I am not sure how to explain it better. We have a very extensive HTTPD configuration in Puppet and I am trying to make the smallest possible change to have a similar configuration in HAProxy - specifically, I don't want to duplicate all the manifests.

Comment: I already answered that question. Please respond with your interest in the various solutions offered for the first and second questions and we can proceed.

Comment: I see how I would use exported resources for the first issue. I am not sure I understand how that would help in the second question.